# Drag and drop file with Playwright

Tags: typescript, drag-and-drop, playwright

I'm trying to drag and drop a .csv file to an webpage in Playwright and using Typescript, but the file is not being dropped.

I was following this issue https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10667#issuecomment-998397241.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
  const fileBuffer: Buffer = await fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './../../files/ci_file.csv'));

        console.log('File Readed');
        // Create the DataTransfer and File
        await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

        const dataTransfer = await page.evaluateHandle((fileBuffer) => {
            const dt = new DataTransfer();
        
            console.log('Reached here!!');
        
           const file = new File([fileBuffer], 'ci_file.csv', { type: 'application/csv' });
           dt.items.add(file);
           return dt ;
          }, fileBuffer.toString('hex'));
        
        console.log('File Created the DataTransfer and File');
          
        // Now dispatch
        await page.dispatchEvent('#base_page', 'drop', { dataTransfer });
```

Also this **console.log('Reached here!!'); ** is not printed in my console. Can someone help me? Thanks!